# GetValue Nested Input JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html:

```
<div class="Alaves">
<h4>Admin</h4>
<input type="hidden" value=1>
</div>
//...There I have 10 class="Alaves" with inputs
```

And I need if clicked show its value; But its not working.

And my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Alaves').click(function () {
        assert( this.getElementsByTagName('input').val);
    });
});
```

Comment: want you to find val of input youclicked ?

Comment: first, change value=1 to value="1"

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you mean:

```
$(function (){
    $('.Alaves').click(function (){
        $("input", this).each(function(){
            assert(this.value);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Alaves').click(function () {
        assert( $(this).val());
        or
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Alaves').click(function () {
            assert($(this).children('input').val());
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the value of input you clicked you need to use value function as `.val()` and not `.val`. Also you should find the input element in the current clicked element using the `find()` method of jquery

```js
$(function (){
    $('.Alaves').click(function (){
        console.log($(this).find('input').val());
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Alaves">
<h4>Admin</h4>
<input type="hidden" value=1>
</div>
<div class="Alaves">
<h4>Admin</h4>
<input type="hidden" value=2>
</div>

<div class="Alaves">
<h4>Admin</h4>
<input type="hidden" value=3>
</div>
<div class="Alaves">
<h4>Admin</h4>
<input type="hidden" value=4>
</div>
<div class="Alaves">
<h4>Admin</h4>
<input type="hidden" value=5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On click if you want to show its child text box value only then :

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('.Alaves').click(function () {
             assert( $(this).find('input').first().val();
            });
         });
```

else for all input having same parent class "Alaves"
@prasad answer can be follow

Answer (score 0):

Snippeted solution:

```js
$( function() {
  $( '.alaves' ).click( function() {
    assert( $( 'input:hidden', this ).val() );
  });
});

function assert( val ) {
  console.log( 'Input\'s value is: "' + val + '".' );
}
```

```css
.alaves {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alaves">
  <h4>Admin</h4>
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
</div>
```

I corrected some mistakes and bad practices.